# UTF-8 encoding in c

Tags: c, linux, utf-8

what is `UTF-8` encoding? I google it but could not able to understand what it is. Please explain in simple words and example.

Next I need to encode one string in `UTF-8` encoding. I got `openssl` but it is converting in only `base64` format.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct some
{
    char string[40];
};

int main() 
{
    string *s;
    char str[9];
    gets(str);
    strcpy(s,str);
    /*Now how to get emcoded form of "Hello" in UTF-8*/
    /*printf("encoded data");
    return 0;
}
```

Those strings are available at `runtime` so do not anything about what is coming. and after encoding need to store them in `DB`.

I checked it on `SO` itself but could not find any source in `c`, it is available in `.net` `java` `c#`. I am using `linux Redhat`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8 is a good place to start, much better than SO

Comment: You need to understand what encodings are, and the difference between bytes and text.

Comment: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: UTF-8 from "Hello" is "Hello".

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky... it is right... but I am not getting from where I need to start coing to convert string in `UTF-8` format

Answer (score 2):

Encodings describe what bytes or sequence of bytes correspond to what characters. ASCII is the simplest encoding. In ASCII a single byte value corresponds to a single character. Unfortunately there are more than 255 characters in the world. UTF-8 is probably the most common encoding format because it is compatible with english ASCII, but also allows international characters. If you write a standard english string in C it is already UTF-8. "Hello" == "Hello"

Joel has a fantastic article about this subject called: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

It does a good job of explaining ASCII, unicode, and UTF8 string encodings.

> In UTF-8, every code point from 0-127 is stored in a single byte. Only
>   code points 128 and above are stored using 2, 3, in fact, up to 4 (not 6, corrected by R.)
>   bytes.

Comment: so if I covert it in ASCII... my job is done?

Comment: @Krishna it already is done. When you write out english strings in C, they are the ASCII character set and in turn UTF-8 compatible

Comment: @justin... Actually I am getting those strings at runtime, so I dont know what they are? And after encoding I need to store them in DB. I am a naive so not able to understand what to do.

Comment: @Krishna if you are loading them from an unknown source then the encoding is unknown without sniffing the patterns or some sort of metadata. Do you have reason to think that the strings loaded at runtime are not ASCII or UTF-8?

Comment: @Justin... Actually I dont.... I was just asked to do so for some characters which I am not able to store in DB, like URLs... so idea is that we need to encode them and after that when we need that we fetch data from db and decode that....

Comment: @Krishna encode/decode to what? usually your application works at the utf-8 level. The UTF8 of a url is just the url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36362/discussion-between-krishna-and-justin-meiners)

Comment: One small detail: UTF-8 is only up to 4 bytes, not 6. This is the definition used by all the standards that deal with UTF-8. Early definitions allowed up to 6 bytes, representing values up to 2^31-1, but this is not useful and in fact has some harmful properties.

Comment: @R.. Joels article must be outdated